# Can I import configuration files with supervisord?

Tags: environment-variables, supervisord

I have a Hubot instance whose source code is public, but it needs some API keys which I need to keep secret.

My server configuration files `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` I also want to keep public, so others can see my configuration. As a result, I can't write:

```
[program:hubot]
environment=API_KEY=12345
...
```

I've tried writing a bash wrapper script which isn't public and contains my secret API keys:

```
#!/bin/bash

export API_KEY=12345
~/src/handybot/bin/hubot -a xmpp
```

and calling it from supervisor:

```
[program:hubot]
command=/home/hubot/run_hubot.sh
```

This works, but the hubot process is not monitored by supervisor, only the bash process. As a result, if I do `supervisorctl restart hubot`, I end up with two hubot instances.

Is it possible to `include` other files in supervisor configuration files? I've also found [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) but I'd have to hack Hubot itself to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand the part about wanting to keep `conf.d` public (why do that?), but aside from that, try using `exec` in the last line of the shell script:

```
exec ~/src/handybot/bin/hubot -a xmpp
```

Alternatively you can usually pass env vars like

```
ABC=2 DEF=3 ~/src/handybot/bin/hubot -a xmpp
```

I say "usually" only because I haven't tested it in supervisor.